# Zero-beta assets and the Sharpe-Lintner CAPM

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, capm, diversification

I'm reading *The Capital Asset Pricing Model: Theory and Evidence* (Fama and French, 2004) and came across the following statement:

"A risky asset’s return is uncorrelated with the market
return—its beta is zero—when the average of the asset’s covariances with the
returns on other assets just offsets the variance of the asset’s return. Such a risky
asset is riskless in the market portfolio in the sense that it contributes nothing to the
variance of the market return."

To express this statement algebraically would it be sufficient to show that if $Cov(R_i, R_M) = 0$, then the variance of a portfolio made up of risky asset i and the market portfolio would be:

$$\sigma_p^2 = \sigma_i^2 + \sum_{t=1}^{n} x_{i}Cov(R_i, R_M) = \sigma_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{i}x_{j}Cov(R_i, R_j) $$, where $x_i$ is the weight of asset i in the market portfolio?